# The square root of natural number expressed by an infinite series

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, sequences-and-series, elementary-proofs, irrational-numbers

Can you prove or disprove the following claim:

> Let $U(n,P,Q)$ be the nth [generalized Lucas number of the first kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas_sequence#Recurrence_relations) and let $m$ be a natural number. Then,
> $$\sqrt{m}=1+\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n+1} \cdot (m-1)^n}{U(n,2,1-m) \cdot U(n+1,2,1-m)}$$

The SageMath cell that demonstrates this claim can be found [here](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJxdjUEKwkAQBO--Yo892Q3Z1qP4iTwgEiVKwBl1Nvt_IwQE-9RUF7SeDjzuXj7bgr4HY6kKoKUMsEhpoN9u0uFRr2M5W9XL5ISlfWKr0vzhyG2QcHt6sDBb8NHuE5iYc5Y1v7_y9gWrKx-HHydx&lang=sage&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ==).

Comment: Not sure if it helps, but using Mathematica I found that $U(n,2,1-m)$ has the explicit formula $U(n,2,1-m)=\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor n/2 \rfloor} \binom{n}{2k+1} m^k$. This should be easy to prove using the generating function.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

So, here we have $P=2$ and $Q=1-m$.

Notice that
$$\frac{Q^n}{U_n(P,Q)U_{n+1}(P,Q)} = \frac{U_{n+1}(P,Q)}{U_n(P,Q)}-\frac{U_{n+2}(P,Q)}{U_{n+1}(P,Q)}.$$
By telescoping, it follows that
$$\sum_{n=1}^k \frac{Q^n}{U_n(P,Q)U_{n+1}(P,Q)} = P - 
\frac{U_{k+2}(P,Q)}{U_{k+1}(P,Q)}.$$
Taking the limit over $k\to\infty$, we get
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{Q^n}{U_n(P,Q)U_{n+1}(P,Q)} = \frac{P-\mathrm{sgn}(P)\sqrt{P^2-4Q}}2 = 1 - \sqrt{m}.$$
QED